# How to upload only one file on a server in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload

I want to upload a file on a server using Angular.
I used this link:
[https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-upload-component-with-express](http://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-upload-component-with-express) 
to attach multiple files.

But I want to attach only one file and upload only one file.
Here is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularizjqax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupload%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.html

```
<input type="file" #file style="display: none" (change)="onFilesAdded()"/>
<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Upload Files</h1>
  <div>
    <button [disabled]="uploading || uploadSuccessful" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="add-files-btn" (click)="addFiles()">
      Add Files
    </button>
  </div>

  <!-- This is the content of the dialog, containing a list of the files to upload -->
  <mat-dialog-content fxFlex>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let file of files">
        <h4 mat-line>{{file.name}}</h4>
        <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="progress" mode="determinate" [value]="progress[file.name].progress | async"></mat-progress-bar>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-dialog-content>

  <!-- This are the actions of the dialog, containing the primary and the cancel button-->
  <mat-dialog-actions class="actions">
    <button *ngIf="showCancelButton" mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!canBeClosed" (click)="closeDialog()">{{primaryButtonText}}</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

I want the user to only be able to attach one file, if the user tries to attach again, the first attachment should be removed and only the latest attached file should be shown.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izjqax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupload%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.html

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I am able to attached multiple file , but I need only attached one file

Comment: I want user only attached only one file, if user try to again attached it removed first one and show latest attached file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) which demonstrating how to make a component upload file.

The idea is having an input to receive the file

**HTML** : Add yourself the stuff malcoded

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Upload Files</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="file" (change)="selFile($event.target.files)">
  </div>
  <button (click)="startUpload()">Upload</button>
```

Then, upload it

**Component**

```
  selectedFile: any;
  selFile(event: FileList) {
    this.selectedFile = event.item(0);
  }
  startUpload() {
    const file = this.selectedFile;
    //call web service to upload
  }
```

Comment: can you change my `link`

Comment: can you share stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izjqax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupload%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.html

Comment: @user944513 glad to help you